# Using the Ionic framework with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Can one use the Ionic framework with plain Javascript (aka. without the recommended frameworks like react, angular or vue)?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can build Ionic apps using VanillaJS or take advantage of Vue, React or Angular or Stencil

all components documentation is available for JavaScript.

it's recommended to use React or Vue,... for large-scale applications but if you want to use plain JS it's available.

From the Ionic framework [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/#javascript):

> One of the main goals of moving Ionic to Web Components was to remove any hard requirement on a single framework to host the components. This made it possible for the core components to work standalone on a web page with just a script tag

Answer (score 0):

In short: Yes, in the same as way you can use wordpress.

According to the [official documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs):

> One of the main goals with moving Ionic to Web Components was to remove any hard requirement on a single framework to host the components. This made it possible for the core components to work standalone in a web page with just a script tag. While working with frameworks can be great for larger teams and larger apps, it is now possible to use Ionic as a standalone library in a single page even in a context like WordPress.